# Reactjs/Javascript the most efficient way to print to printer a 2d array into table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, electron

I'm currently using **Electron + Reactjs/Javascript** to develop an appplication. I'm just wondering if anyone know any efficient way to print (e.g. using something like `window.print()`) a large 2D array (say 500000 by 500000) onto printer.

My current effort to produce the table:

```
printTable(dataArray) { 
   var tableDiv = document.createElement('table')
   var bodyDiv = document.createElement('tbody')
   for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
      var trDiv = document.createElement('tr')
      for (var j = 0; j < dataArray[i].length; j++) {
           trDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<td>dataArray[i][j]</td>');
      }
      tbody.appendChild(trDiv);
   }
   tableDiv.appendChild(tbody);
}
```

I think my electron window crashes while it's creating the table. Does anyone know any good ways of printing the array?

Comment: 500000 x 500000 is 250 billion elements. Are you sure it's necessary to show all those in a table??

Comment: Not neccessarily, as long as i can print all the cells and break the page at appropriate locations, it's completely fine. At the end of the day, i have to print all cells, so i'm not sure how fast it will get if i make subtables instead of one giant table.

Comment: Have to kill a lot of trees for that print job